# Induced-EMF due to the induced magnetic field of a wire?

Tags: electromagnetism

If a current carrying wire is placed inside a magnetic field(B), the wire will produce it's own magnetic field that will oppose the applied external magnetic field(B). Due to the two fields opposing one another, would that somehow change the ϕ acting on the wire inducing an ϵ to oppose that change?

I'm aware that this wire would experience the Lorentz Force, and from that will move and from that motion, there is induced ϵ = −vBL.

Comment: Why would a current carrying wire in a magnetic field produce its own magnetic field in opposition? Isn't the magnetic field around a current-carrying wire a function of the current in that wire, and wouldn't whether it opposes some other field or not depend on what that other field is?

Comment: @PhilFrost I'm not sure myself... But the wire would produce a magnetic field, I related Lenz-law to assume it's in opposition. I'm not sure how that wire's field would interact with the exterior field, could you clarify my confusion here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A current carrying wire will always generate its magnetic field, if this is going to be opposite to the external field or not, depends in which direction the current flows.

That beeing said, there will be no induced voltage if there will be no flux change. For flux to change you can either keep the outer field constant and change the area (e.g. move the wire) or you keep the area constant and change the external field, or change the current in the wire, thus changing the total flux in the area.

Comment: Wouldn't the wire's own magnetic field oppose/attract the external magnetic field causing a flux change?

Comment: Assuming the wire's current is constant.

Comment: Or to be exact, the wire's magnetic field would increase/decrease the total magnetic field( B(External)+ B(wire) = Btot)causing change in magnetic flux, and a induced-EMF to oppose that?

Comment: Yes. However once the flux is static no voltage will be induced. So the way you described the problem, the change already happened and you have a static flux, so no induced voltage.

Comment: In a motor like application when might you think this could happen? Or when a current-carrying wire is placed in a magnetic field and starts to move due to the Lorentz force?

Comment: The mere placement of a current carying wire in a static field would cause an induced voltage due to total flux and area change. Then once the wire and current are stationary no induced voltage is generated. If you then start to move the wire, you change the area of the loop, which causes the flux to change and you have induced a voltage.